# can we alter datomic enums or can we add any new values to datomic enums?

Tags: clojure, datomic

For example I have following structure

```
{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]  
 :db/ident :persons/gender  
 :db/valueType :db.type/ref  
 :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one  
 :db/doc "A person's gender enum reference"  
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}  

;; :persons/gender enum values  
{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user]  
 :db/ident :persons.gender/male}  

{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user]  
 :db/ident :persons.gender/female}
```

and after designing i want to add one more attribute to existing structure 
is it possible with datomic..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you aren't really altering the DB schema, just adding a new allowed value so it doesn't conflict with any existing data. This case is not described as *schema alteration* as you can check here http://docs.datomic.com/schema.html

Comment: oh..!!
thank you and
is there any option to rename existing attr like sql?

Comment: Of course, the answer is on the same link, don't get offended but you should search a little bit more. To rename a :db/ident, submit a transaction with the :db/id and the value of the new :db/ident. This example alters the :db/ident of :person/name to be :person/full-name.

`[{:db/id :person/name
  :db/ident :person/full-name}]`

Answer (score -5):

You may find that [Tupelo Datomic](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/src/tupelo/datomic.adoc) can help with your use case.  It is a user-friendly library to make interacting with Datomic easier and more effortless.